# System.net.mail email are landing in Spam/Junk

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, email

I am sending Email from SMTP server and all my Emails are landed in Junk in Hotmail ,Live and Yahoo. I am not using any Spam like content and following all the guildline to send Emails.

I check on mail to identify the Issues and found quite a few issues below

1. HELO Greeting Check

   Description: Email Server HELO is . HELO greeting does not contain a valid domain. We would recommend to have a valid domain in HELO greeting. Ideally HELO greeting should be the same as Email server host name (in FQDN format).
2. BATV (Bounce Address Tag Validation) Check

   Description: Email server is not using BATV format while sending out emails. BATV is recommended to ensure that your users do not become a victim of bounce floods.
3. DKIM (Domain Keys Identified Mail) Check

   Description: Email does not contain any DKIM/Domain Keys Signature and the published Domain Keys policy rejects such unsigned emails. Therefore it is very likely that your emails are considered SPAM by Email servers verifying Domain keys. Signing your Outbound emails as per your Domain Keys policy will minimize chances of your Email being considered as SPAM.

I have no Idea How to set the Helo Greeting, BATV and DKIM. . This is become very critical.

I am using ASP.net and IIS 6  as a technology . I am wounding could anybody Help me to do these things

Comment: Are you sending mails via a local SMTP server?

Comment: I faced similar issue, but fixed by setting proper sender email.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Atwood wrote a pretty nice blogpost on sending email, "[So You'd Like to Send Some Email (Through Code)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)". Recommended reading..

Answer (score 0):

Simple: At the end CONFIGURE YOUR EMAIL SERVER.

> Description: Email Server HELO is . HELO greeting does not contain a valid domain

This is because - you did not configrue it.

> 2) BATV (Bounce Address Tag Validation) Check

Never heard of, should not be an issue.

> 3) DKIM (Domain Keys Identified Mail) Check

Same here. This is not supported by most email servers. Change server to one supporting, then set it up IF you need to.

I think your main issue is (1) (no valid HELO domain) and that is a pure admin laziness. You look like a spammer.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your issue but... another suggestion is that **if** you're sending email from the account, say test@test.com for example, and your SMTP server is not on that domain I.e.  SMTP.test.com the receiving email server see's that someone outside the domain is trying to send mail on behalf of that domain.